# Write huge pyspark dataframe to EFS in parquets

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, amazon-efs

I have huge data files of total 25 GB of size. I am reading whole data into pyspark dataframe using `spark.read.load(filenamesList, format='csv', header=None)` and writing the entire dataframe to multiple parquets based on value of column 'mycolumn' using `df.write.partitionBy('mycolumn').parquet(path to EFS location)`. At this step I am getting this error:
`java.io.IOException: No space left on device`

Since I am writing files to EFS location there should not be the space issue. Can someone please help me to understand this?